# Help on question regarding proper classes and class of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

`Show that the class of ordinals α with $$ℵ_α^{ℵ_0} = ℵ_α$$ is a
proper class. Then show that the class of ordinals α with $$ℵ_α^{ℵ_0}>ℵ_α$$  is
also a proper class.

What i have so far: So this one has given me lots of trouble since i cant assume the  Generalised Continuum Hypothesis. But my idea is to some how use co final characters to some how show there is a surjection. But thats all i have as an idea, if anyone can offer hints that will help very much

Comment: Please use MathJax. You can find a detailed tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you i was able to edit the post to make it more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that if $\lambda=\kappa^{\aleph_0}$, then $\lambda^{\aleph_0}=\lambda$.

Secondly, recall König's theorem, and its consequence: $\kappa<\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$.

Comment: Is $\kappa=\aleph_\alpha$?

Comment: It's some arbitrary cardinal, yeah.

Comment: So does that mean for the first equality $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\alpha$ would work for all $\alpha$  since $$\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0\aleph_0}=\aleph_\alpha^\aleph_0$$

Comment: No, you're not reading this correctly.

Comment: Ok going to the inequality $$ℵ_α^{ℵ_0}>ℵ_α$$, by Konig's Theorem $$ℵ_α<ℵ_α^{cf(ℵ_α)}=ℵ_α^{ℵ_0}$$ for countable limit ordinals right?

Comment: But i do not believe that is a proper class

Comment: Yes, but there is a proper class of ordinals with countable cofinality.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the formulae for powers of cardinals?

Hausdorff formula, for all $n \in \omega$:

$$\aleph_{\alpha +n}^{\aleph_\beta} = {\aleph_\alpha}^{\aleph_\beta} \aleph_{\alpha + n}$$

Tarski formula: for $\alpha$ a limit ordinal and $\beta < cf(\alpha)$, so certainly for $\beta = 0$:

$$\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_\beta}  = \sum_{\gamma < \alpha} \aleph_\gamma^{\aleph_\beta} $$

This will maybe help evaluate the different ${\aleph_\alpha}^{\aleph_0}$, as a start: for $\alpha = 0$ we have that it equals $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$